# Gstreamer on windows

Tags: windows, dll, gstreamer

I'd like to build application using  Gstreamer 1.0 and GTK+-3.0 on Windows 8 (64bit).

I have sucessfully install and build GTK+-3.0, 32 bit version using Dev-C++ and Mingw 32-bit (there is no 64 bit version of GTK+). Everything works perferkt. It also installed pkg-config, I addeded it in %PATH% and it works.

I have installed gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86-1.4.4.msi and gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.4.4.msi from [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.4.4/)

1) First problem: it installed itself into I:\gstreamer\ without asking me. I am very unhappy about it, I'd like have it on C:. But its not the biggest problem.

2) pkg-config do not know about gstreamer. I have found in I:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\pkgconfig\ *.pc files, so I looked into gstreamer-1.0.pc and added to my projekt this options:

C compiler:
-I"I:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0/"
Linker:
-L"I:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib" -lgstreamer-1.0

3) Now the program was compiled, but when I run it, it was not able to find gstreamer-1.0-0.dll. So i tried copy I:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin\gstreamer-1.0-0.dll into to the same directory as is my compiled file. Then it was not able to find libwinptread-1.dll. So I copied it also.

Then te program run, but it faild with some error like "cannot find entry point to windows thread ..." (I do not remember it exactly). So I copied ALL dll files from  I:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin\ and then finally the program run.

But now it is not able to create elements:

```
source = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "source");
//source is null
```

So, my question is, how to install gstreamer, that my program will find all dll files and will be able to create elements?

Answer (score 2):

1. installing -- choose "custom install", there  you can change the installation path.
2. for vs you can use *.props (gstreamer\1.0\x86\share\vs\2010\libs)
3. you need set Environment variable - GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH_1_0 to plug-ins. For more details see http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html